# Tool to transpile from js to jsx

Tags: javascript, babeljs, reactjs

I'm curious if any of the transpiling tools will convert from plain JS to JSX. Babel will transpile JSX to JS, but as far as I know it cannot go back to JSX.

From the [example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#the-transform):

```
var Nav;
// Input (JSX):
var app = <Nav color="blue" />;
// Output (JS):
var app = React.createElement(Nav, {color:"blue"});
```

Are there tools that go the other direction:

```
var Nav;
// Input (JS):
var app = React.createElement(Nav, {color:"blue"});
// Output (JSX):
var app = <Nav color="blue" />;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this haha. The point of JSX is to make it easy to write React components. Not to retroactively make React components easier to understand for the developer. If you're looking for something to help with debugging, try the official developer tools: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html

Comment: Hey JCD, thanks for the response. The reason to do this is inheriting an app that was written using `React.createElement`. I'd like to replace all `React.createElement`s with the jsx version.

Comment: I doubt such a thing exists. Your best bet is probably to find the original author and ask them for the source JSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but there is apparently now a babel plugin to do exactly what you ask.

`babel-js-to-jsx`

https://github.com/JoeStanton/babel-js-to-jsx

Per the documentation:

> Babel 6 plugin to convert from desugared React.DOM CallExpressions ->
>   the equivalent JSX. Currently used to migrate to ES6+ from other
>   compile to JS languages.
>
> It can be used as a plugin:

```
require("babel-core").transform(code, {
  plugins: ["js-to-jsx", "syntax-jsx"],
}).code
```

> Or from the command line for composition with
>   other tools:

```
npm install babel-plugin-js-to-jsx
cat example.ls | lsc -cb --no-header | js-to-jsx | esformatter -c format.json
```

Comment: Is there an alternative? I couldn't with this one.